# Multidimensional Array showing data

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
categories Object
(
    [_db:categories:private] => db Object
        (
            [_pdo] => PDO Object
                (
                )

            [_query] => PDOStatement Object
                (
                    [queryString] => SELECT * FROM categories WHERE  name_of_category = ?
                )

            [_error] => 
            [_results] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [name_of_category] => Vedran
                            [description_of_category] => adsdasdas
                            [meta_keywords] => sadasdas
                            [meta_description] => asdasdas
                            [notes] => sadsadas
                            [created] => 2016-01-20 08:26:02
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [name_of_category] => VEdran
                            [description_of_category] => ddddd
                            [meta_keywords] => qsqddd
                            [meta_description] => sqdddd
                            [notes] => sddd
                            [created] => 2020-01-16 00:00:00
                        )

                )

            [_count] => 2
        )

    [_fields:categories:private] => 
)
```

Hello. Can someone help me please with this array. I have created in database categories table. I would like to show categories on page where user would be able to manage categories (delete, edit). When i want to show categories from database i get this array in PHP. Now i dont know how to show for example only "name_of_category" on web page. Can someone please help me.

Comment: What's your code to query the database ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $categories=$ObjVariable->_results;
```

then use the $categories array to display the values